# PostgreSQL 9.3: How to insert upper case UUID into table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table with only 1 column that is `id` which is of type `UUID`.

**Table**: `uuidtest`

```
create table uuidtest
(
id uuid
);
```

**Insertion**:

I have generated uuid by using `uuid_generate_v4()` and also done it upper case 
and inserting it into the table.

Try1:

```
insert into uuidtest values('{4B36AFC8-5205-49C1-AF16-4DC6F96DB982}');
```

Try2:

```
insert into uuidtest values('4B36AFC8-5205-49C1-AF16-4DC6F96DB982');
```

Now see the result:

```
select * from uuidtest;
```

**Ouptput**:

```
id
uuid
-------------------------------------
4b36afc8-5205-49c1-af16-4dc6f96db982
4b36afc8-5205-49c1-af16-4dc6f96db982
```

I have also tried it to update:

```
update uuidtest
set id = upper(id::text)::uuid
```

**But**: The  output remain the same:

```
id
uuid
-------------------------------------
4b36afc8-5205-49c1-af16-4dc6f96db982
4b36afc8-5205-49c1-af16-4dc6f96db982
```

Comment: How are you using the `uuid`?  Could you convert it to uppercase inside your app layer?

Comment: From doc http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html `PostgreSQL also accepts the following alternative forms for input: use of upper-case digits, the standard format surrounded by braces, omitting some or all hyphens, adding a hyphen after any group of four digits`  and **`Output is always in the standard form.`**

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Yeah! For some tables I have convert it to the uppercase inside my application layer and that is working fine and it not working if I do it manually as I have shown in the above.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is that PostgresSQL will always spit out lowercase uuids.  If you want to uppercase them somewhere else, it is your business.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should note that in PostgreSQL a UUID is a 128 bit number, and is stored as such (not as a string with 36 characters!). What we are discussing are the input and output forms of this type of data.

The [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-uuid.html) says:

> The data type uuid stores Universally Unique Identifiers (UUID) as defined by RFC 4122, ISO/IEC 9834-8:2005, and related standards.
>
> ...
>
> PostgreSQL also accepts the following alternative forms for input: use of upper-case digits, the standard format surrounded by braces, omitting some or all hyphens, adding a hyphen after any group of four digits.
>
> ...
>
> Output is always in the standard form.

The [RFC 4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) says:

> Each field is treated as an integer and has its value printed as a
> zero-filled hexadecimal digit string with the most significant
> digit first.  The hexadecimal values "a" through "f" are output as
> lower case characters and are case insensitive on input.

In other words, to follow the standard, the value is *always* printed as lower case.

Of course, if you want to produce the result with upper case letters, you could use something like:

```
select upper(id::TEXT) from uuidtest;
```

Comment: And to add to this answer, if you need to _display_ the `uuid` in uppercase, you can do so inside your app layer.

Comment: You mean `select UPPER(id::text)`? Otherwise `ERROR: function upper(uuid) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types.`

Comment: @Renzo, Obviously! I can get the result with uppercase by using `upper()` but my question is can I able to store it uppercase while inserting?

Comment: The value is stored as 128 bit number, not as a string! See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah thats right. If inserted in Postgres, it will force the values to go to lowercase. What I tried was bit different and may not be usable for everyone i.e; may not be practical. If you want UUIDs in upper case in Postgres then use ID as this one:

```
    String id = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase();
```

[Snipped picture to show IDs in CAPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhf29.jpg)

Also, if this is not useful you have to try as others mentioned above:
DB generated UUID in lower:

```
select uuid_generate_v4();
```

in UPPER:

```
select UPPER(uuid_generate_v4()::text);
```

Comment: A uuid is not stored in lowercase. It's stored as a number and numbers don't have "lower" or "uppercase". What you are doing is not storing a uuid, but storing a string representation of a uuid which is far less efficient. Rather then storing more then twice the amount of data (36 bytes vs 16bytes) it would be more efficient to create a view that retuns the `uuid` as an uppercased string.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I understand that I am storing a String and manually making it in Upper case but when I generated UUID or UUID2 in postgreSQL with Hibernate hbm configuration it was always stored in Lower Case. Any idea why it is storing everything in lowercase?

Comment: It is not "storing" it in lowercase because Postgres stores a binary representation of the UUID which has no notion "upper" or "lower" case. It only _displays_ the UUID in lowercase.