# How to INSERT a reference to UUID from another table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, uuid

I'm learning to use Sequelize to use with a PostgreSQL database. All of the following is happening on a dev. environment. This happened while manually trying to insert data into my tables to check if things are setup correctly through Sequelize, check on failing unit tests, etc.

I've made two tables with Sequelize models: User and Publication. Both these tables are generating UUIDv4. I've associated the User `hasMany` Publications, and Publication `belongsTo` User (you may reference the extra info).

On my `psql` shell, I've inserted the following record to my User table (rest of the data cut out for brevity):

```
|                   id                   |  firstName | lastName  | ..| 
|----------------------------------------|------------|-----------|---|
|  8c878e6f-ee13-4a37-a208-7510c2638944  |   Aiz      |    ....   |...|
```

Now I'm trying to insert a record into my Publication table while referencing my newly created user above. Here's what I entered into the shell:

```
INSERT INTO "Publications"("title", "fileLocation", ..., "userId")VALUES('How to Pasta', 'www.pasta.com', ..., 8c878e6f-ee13-4a37-a208-7510c2638944);
```

It fails and I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "c878e6f"
LINE 1: ...8c878e6f-ee...
```

(it points to the second character on the terminal in LINE 1 reference - the 'c').

**What's wrong here? Are we supposed to enter UUIDs another way if we want to do it manually in psql? Do we paste the referenced UUID as a string? Is there a correct way I'm missing from my own research?**

---

### Some extra info if it helps:

From my models:

```
Publication.associate = function(models) {
  // associations can be defined here
  Publication.belongsTo(models.User, {
    foreignKey: "userId" 
  });
};
```

and

```
User.associate = function(models) {
  // associations can be defined here
  User.hasMany(models.Publication, {
    foreignKey: "userId",
    as: "publications"
  });
};
```

Here's how I've defined `userId` in Publication:

```
userId: {
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  references: {
    model: "User",
    key: "id",
    as: "userId"
  }
}
```

If it's worth anything, my (primaryKey) `id` on both models are `type: DataTypes.UUID, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4` (I don't know if this is an issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

surround your uuid in apostrophes (write it as a string) and pg will convert it to a uuid

Starting and ending your string with {} is optional

Eg

```
INSERT INTO "Publications"("title", "fileLocation", ..., "userId")VALUES('How to Pasta', 'www.pasta.com', ..., '8c878e6f-ee13-4a37-a208-7510c2638944');
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO "Publications"("title", "fileLocation", ..., "userId")VALUES('How to Pasta', 'www.pasta.com', ..., '{8c878e6f-ee13-4a37-a208-7510c2638944}');
```

Source (I don't do pgsql much so I casted around for another person who wrote some working pgsql. If this doesn't work out for you let me know and I'll remove the answer): [PostgreSQL 9.3: How to insert upper case UUID into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585957/postgresql-9-3-how-to-insert-upper-case-uuid-into-table)

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if this was the case since postgres has a UUID type. However, it seems that the type is only useful for generating UUIDs vs storing into as a string in reference fields. Nevertheless, this makes the manual entry work.

Comment: If you've declared your column type as uuid then when you pass the string pgsql will cast and store it as a uuid, surely.. It is passed as a string as without it it looks like things subtracted from each other, hence th syntax error. They probably could have come up with some other delimiter but that is more work for developers to remember yet another quirk, when casting from a string is easy and works and nothing to remember :)